# Regex not equal to string

Tags: .net, regex

I'm banging my head against a wall with a regular expression. I'm trying to define an expression that excludes exactly this text 'System' (case insensitive), but can contain
the word 'System' providing it's not just that.

Examples:

- System == INVALID
- SYSTEM == INVALID
- system == INVALID
- syStEm == INVALID
- asd SysTem == Valid
- asd System asd == Valid
- System asd == Valid
- asd System == Valid
- asd == Valid

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?!system$)
```

Or this to match the whole line:

```
^(?!system$).*$
```

The regex has a negative look-ahead on its beginning, which doesn't match if "system" is the entire string.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the ?! operator work? I've never used that one (though I've used pretty much regex I tend to find solutions which don't use 'not').

Comment: @Alxandr - it checks what follows your current position. For example, `c(?!4)` will match c from `Doc12`, but not the c on `Doc42`. A look-around doesn't capture, so I don't have to worry about replacing the digit, or check edge case (for example, if c were the last character: `Doc`).

Comment: If you don't care about matching the whole line (if you only care about it matching the pattern or not), adding `.*$` doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: @x-yuri - Right, that's the first option. I you're just filtering string, for example, `.*$` is not needed.

Comment: I'm trying this in a sql engine and it gives "invalid perl operator" - is there a PCRE equivalent?

Comment: @dcsan - This should work with [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC19). On SQL these are usually easier, because you can combine multiple regex patterns using `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT`. The example here doesn't require a regex, it can be `WHERE x != 'system'`

Answer (score 5):

Reject if it matches `^system$` (make sure `i` flag is ON).

Comment: This should be the first option, or course. I naturally (and possibly wrongly) assumed the OP cannot do it.

Comment: I can't use this because I'm using a system that uses rules and the rule has to match a regex, I don't have the option to say apply the rule if the regex doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

```
^$|^.{1-5}$|.{7}|^[^s]|^.[^y]|^..[^s]|^...[^t]|[^e].$|[^m]$
```

But use amarghosh's answer if you can.

(updated as per suggestion below)

Comment: heh, I wrote that without testing it. I'm kind of shocked that it actually worked first try. The first two clauses are redundant though, so: 
(^.{1-6}$)|(.{8})|(^[^s])|(^.[^y])|(^..[^s])|(^...[^t])|([^e].$)|([^m]$)

Nice tip about ?! though - I hadn't heard of it.

Comment: oops. that regex lets through "systuem". (and fails on empty string, which is apparently acceptable?)
try:
^$|^.{1-5}$|.{7}|^[^s]|^.[^y]|^..[^s]|^...[^t]|[^e].$|[^m]$

Comment: Steve - Welcome to stack overflow. It is best to update your answer than to add another one as a comment. Also, start the regex line with 4 spaces - it will format it as code.

Answer (score -1):

To match all the words of COMMON_LOGGER except for COMMON_LOGGER. (i.e., not followed by a dot), you can use the negative lookahead assertion (?!.) to exclude any matches that are immediately followed by a dot. Here's an example regex:
c6290d3a-e1c4-41f5-b45b-6afdb1cfe3b2

```
COMMON_LOGGER(?!\.)
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the (13 year old, badly written) question?