# Regex not equals to 3 strings

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, regex-negation

I've already seen [Regex not equal to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964645/regex-not-equal-to-string) and [Regular expression for a string that does not start with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence) but I can't find the right solution to my regular expression.

I need to do this: "if my HOST doesn't start with eiter `s`, `m` or `www` like (`s.example.whatever`, `m.example.whatever` or `www.example.whatever`) then redirect it to `www.example.whatever`.

Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((.+)\.)+example\.(.+)$
RewriteCond %2 ^(?!s|m|www$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

It doesn't work after many tries at https://regex101.com/
What am I missing?

Comment: what's the website'a actual name?

Comment: @AmitJoki www.example.com.

Comment: @vks if I do this, then some s.example.whatever would be redirected, which i dont want (= i dont want to touch (`s.example.whatever`, `m.example.whatever` or `www.example.whatever`)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negation in `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(s|m|www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```